# Mono Development Environment on Win 7 64bit gmcs hello.cs -pkg:gtk-sharp-2.0 can't find files

Tags: windows, mono, gtk#

I downloaded Mono and installed it on Win 7 64bit

I went to this site to follow the instructions http://www.mono-project.com/Mono_Basics

I opened up the mono command prompt and compiled and ran the console hello world

then I tried to compile the windowed hello world example with

```
gmcs hello.cs -pkg:gtk-sharp-2.0
```

and I get this

```
C:\Code\NoControl\Mono>gmcs hello.cs -pkg:gtk-sharp-2.0
error CS0006: Metadata file `C:/PROGRA\~2/MONO-2\~1.8/lib/mono/gtk-sharp-2.0/pango-sharp.dll' could not be found
error CS0006: Metadata file `C:/PROGRA\~2/MONO-2\~1.8/lib/mono/gtk-sharp-2.0/atk-sharp.dll' could not be found
error CS0006: Metadata file `C:/PROGRA\~2/MONO-2\~1.8/lib/mono/gtk-sharp-2.0/gdk-sharp.dll' could not be found
error CS0006: Metadata file `C:/PROGRA\~2/MONO-2\~1.8/lib/mono/gtk-sharp-2.0/gtk-sharp.dll' could not be found
error CS0006: Metadata file `C:/PROGRA\~2/MONO-2\~1.8/lib/mono/gtk-sharp-2.0/glib-sharp.dll' could not be found
Compilation failed: 5 error(s), 0 warnings
```

How do I fix this?

This is the similar to the question here [cannot compile hello.cs for gtk# using mono command prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9136748/cannot-compile-hello-cs-for-gtk-using-mono-command-prompt) which was not answered.

- Does -pkg work on Windows?
- Do I have to download something extra?
- The abbreviated path mentions ~1.8/ should it say something like ~10.8
  being that  my version of mono is 2.10.8?

Comment: Still the same a year later with `mono-3.2.3` (`mono-3.2.3-gtksharp-2.12.11-win32-0.exe` setup). The installation wizard should have probably  proposed to install mono under another directory, with the path without spaces

Answer (score 9, accepted):

These were helpful answers for pointing out the root cause of the problem.  However, the simplest solution by far is to install Mono into a folder that doesn't have spaces in the name.  While installing, just select something like "C:\SDK\Mono".  Problem solved, and no funky work-arounds necessary.

Comment: Excuse me, but how do you install mono to a custom location? I downloaded the latest version mono-4.0.1-gtksharp-2.12.26-win32-0.msi but there's no place I can choose the installation location during installing, I can only choose to accept the terms and then only the install button without any location specification.

Comment: It seems that the newest mono 4.x (I used mono-4.2.2.30-gtksharp-2.12.30-win32-0.msi) does not allow custom folders for install. So here's what I suggest:
From the command prompt (CMD.EXE), run the following command:

`C:\> mklink /D C:\SDK\Mono "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mono"`

This will create a symbolic link to the installed folder and allow you to use the short path that does not have spaces. Pretty much the work-around that others suggested below.

Answer (score 6):

A work-around I have found to work on Windows 7 where Mono has been installed as a subdirectory of 'Program Files' is to create a folder in the root of C: to hold directory links (for instance called MonoLinks.. NB no space in the name) and then, from a command prompt go into this directory and create a Directory Junction, giving it a name that does not include a space.

```
C:\MonoLinks>mklink /J Mono "C:\Program Files\Mono-2.10.8"
```

This has the effect of creating a traversable directory (link) named Mono that will not only show the contents of the Mono installation but will be accessible to programs without being translated to its original pathname.  This could, just as easily, be created in the root of C: but having a generic folder (MonoLinks) there allows for additional links, if needed, to be created within it without cluttering up the root of C:.

The next thing (which had to be done anyway as the PATH environment variable was not updated during the installation) is to update the PATH environment variable so that it points to the bin directory within the installation.
Within Control Panel, User Accounts, select Change My Environment Variables and edit the PATH variable to include `C:\MonoLinks\Mono\bin` (i.e add semicolon and the path to the end of the PATH property's text).

Comment: Excellent solution! No need to uninstall, then re-install and eventually clutter the c: drive's root folder. Just add the Junction inside your C:\Users\username\bin folder and add it to the path variable.

Answer (score 3):

`-pkg` seems to be flawed on Windows. On a clean command prompt, if you put `Program Files\Mono\bin` on your PATH, `gmcs` will choke on the syntax and will give errors regarding `Files\Mono\...`, indicating an error related to the spaces in the pathname. If you put `PROGRA~1\MONO\bin` on your PATH or use the Mono command prompt, it will choke and give errors regarding `PROGRA\~1/MONO/...`, indicating an error related to tildes (etc.) and escaping them.

Note that although I've given 32-bit examples, there is no reason why this shouldn't apply to 64-bit editions, `PROGRA~2` and `Program Files (x86)`.

A workaround I've found is to give individual `-r[eference]` parameters to gmcs based on the information pkg-config returns, using full paths. Try:

```
gmcs hello.cs -r:C:/PROGRA~2/MONO-2~1.8/lib/mono/gtk-sharp-2.0/gtk-sharp.dll
              -r:C:/PROGRA~2/MONO-2~1.8/lib/mono/gtk-sharp-2.0/gdk-sharp.dll
              ...
```

or better yet:

```
gmcs hello.cs -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mono-2.10.8\lib\mono\..." -r:"..."
```

(i.e. full paths)

If you're using NAnt, try removing `<pkg-references/>` and adding:

```
<include name="C:\Program Files\Mono\lib\mono\gtk-sharp-2.0\gtk-sharp.dll" />
<include name="C:\Program Files\Mono\lib\mono\gtk-sharp-2.0\gdk-sharp.dll" />
...
```

under `<references/>`.

Please excuse my use of inconsistent and incomplete path names; this answer is meant to be a guide, not a copy-paste-solution.

Comment: Corrected the file-name from "gt-sharp.dll" to "gtk-sharp.dll" and enclosed path (with spaces) in quotes (") though neither of this worked for me with `mono-3.2.3-gtksharp-2.12.11-win32-0.exe` while the oher (unaccepted) answers below worked like a charm!