# HelloWorld is successfully launched by Windows .NET but not by MONO

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, mono

I've installed mono on my 64-bit Windows 7 using:

- mono-3.2.3-gtksharp-2.12.11-win32-0.exe
  from [go-mono download page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12984307/200449)

in directory (without spaces in path) changed according to [Jim Gomes' advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12984307/200449)

Successfully run first two examples

- Console Hello World
- Gtk# Hello World

from [Mono Basics](http://mono-project.com/Mono_Basics) article.

But the 3d example "WinForms Hello World" is compiled without errors and run from Windows (by double-clicking in Windows Explorer) successfully but running:

```
mono hello.exe
```

from "Mono-3.2.3 Command Prompt" window produces the errors listed below
(note that first two examples including a window of second example was launched successfully from command prompt invoking through `mono ...`)

What is the problem and how to overcome it?

**UPDATE**
According to mentioned article ["Mono Basics"](http://mono-project.com/Mono_Basics) I compiled the 3d example "Winforms Hello World" with `gmcs hello.cs -pkg:dotnet`.

BTW, where is that `dotnet` package located?
Is it in directory with the same name? I do not have a single dir with exactly such name `dotnet` under Mono-3.2.3 dir

The errors produced by running `mono hello.exe` from "Mono-3.2.3 Command Prompt"

```
Unhandled Exception:
System.TypeInitializationException: 
An exception was thrown by the type initializer for 
System.Windows.Forms.WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext 
---> System.TypeInitializationException: 
An exception was thrown by the type initializer for 
System.Windows.Forms.ThemeEngine ---> System.TypeInitializationException: 
An exception was thrown by the type initializer for 
System.Windows.Forms.ThemeWin32Classic 
---> System.TypeInitializationException: 
An exception was thrown by the type initializer for System.Drawing.KnownColors 
---> System.TypeInitializationException: 
An exception was thrown by the type initializer for System.Drawing.GDIPlus 
---> System.DllNotFoundException: /tmp/install/lib/libgdiplus.so at 
 (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Drawing.GDIPlus:GdiplusStartup 
 (ulong&,System.Drawing.GdiplusStartupInput&,System.Drawing.GdiplusStartupOutput&)
  at System.Drawing.GDIPlus..cctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Drawing.KnownColors..cctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Drawing.Color.get_Black () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Windows.Forms.ThemeWin32Classic..cctor () [0x00000] in <filename unk
nown>:0
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Windows.Forms.ThemeEngine..cctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:
0
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation.get_MenuAccessKeysUnderlined () [0x0
0000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Windows.Forms.Control:.ctor ()
  at System.Windows.Forms.WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext..cctor () [0x00000]
 in <filename unknown>:0
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unkn    own>:0
  at System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unkno    wn>:0
  at System.Windows.Forms.Form..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at HelloWorld..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) HelloWorld:.ctor ()
  at HelloWorld.Main () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.TypeInitializationException: 
  An exception was thrown by the type initializer for  
  System.Windows.Forms.WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext 
     ---> System.TypeInitializationException: 
      An exception was thrown by the type initializer for
      System.Windows.Forms.ThemeEngine 
      ---> System.TypeInitializationException: 
 An exception was thrown by the type initializer for 
      System.Windows.Forms.ThemeWin32Classic 
      ---> System.TypeInitializationException: 
 An exception was thrown by the type initializer for 
       System.Drawing.KnownColors 
        ---> System.TypeInitializationException: 
 An exception was thrown by the type initializer for 
        System.Drawing.GDIPlus 
        ---> System.DllNotFoundException: /tmp/install/lib/libgdiplus.so
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Drawing.GDIPlus:GdiplusStartup                 (ulong&,System.Drawing.GdiplusStartupInput&,System.Drawing.GdiplusStartupOutput&)
  at System.Drawing.GDIPlus..cctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Drawing.KnownColors..cctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Drawing.Color.get_Black () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Windows.Forms.ThemeWin32Classic..cctor () [0x00000] in <filename unk
nown>:0
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Windows.Forms.ThemeEngine..cctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:
0
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation.get_MenuAccessKeysUnderlined () [0x0
0000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Windows.Forms.Control:.ctor ()
  at System.Windows.Forms.WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext..cctor () [0x00000]
 in <filename unknown>:0
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unkn
own>:0
  at System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unkno
wn>:0  
  at System.Windows.Forms.Form..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at HelloWorld..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) HelloWorld:.ctor ()
  at HelloWorld.Main () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Comment: `System.DllNotFoundException: /tmp/install/lib/libgdiplus.so`

Comment: Did you compile it with this parameter: `-pkg:dotnet`?

Comment: Yes, according to mentioned article ["Mono Basics"](http://mono-project.com/Mono_Basics) I compiled the 3d example "Winforms Hello World" with `gmcs hello.cs -pkg:dotnet`. BTW, I am now writing a question to ask where is that damned `dotnet` package (is it in directory with the same name? I do not have a single dir with exactly such name `dotnet` under mono-3.2.3)

Comment: On Ubuntu, this helped for me: `sudo apt-get install libgdiplus`. Don't know how you would do this on Windows, though...

Comment: look for the libgdiplus.dll file in your system, if it's not there, file a bug about this in http://bugzilla.xamarin.com/

Answer (score 5):

I have encountered this problem.

I think this is mono's bug.

If you installed mono in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Mono-3.2.3\etc\mono`

Find the file `C:\Program Files (x86)\Mono-3.2.3\etc\mono\config`

Change Line 29-30:

```
<dllmap dll="gdiplus" target="/tmp/install/lib/libgdiplus.so" />
<dllmap dll="gdiplus.dll" target="/tmp/install/lib/libgdiplus.so" />
```

To:

```
<dllmap dll="gdiplus" target="/tmp/install/lib/libgdiplus.so" os="!windows" />
<dllmap dll="gdiplus.dll" target="/tmp/install/lib/libgdiplus.so" os="!windows" />
```

And this problem will be solved.