# error CS2001: Source file `(x86)/Mono/lib/gtk-sharp-2.0/pango-sharp.dll' could n ot be found

Tags: c#, .net, mono, gtk#

The same issue as the reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9136748/cannot-compile-hello-cs-for-gtk-using-mono-command-prompt):

```
C:\Users\xx\Documents\MonoProject>mcs hello_gtk.cs -pkg:gtk-sharp-2.0
error CS2001: Source file `Files' could not be found
error CS2001: Source file `(x86)/Mono/lib/gtk-sharp-2.0/pango-sharp.dll' could not be found
error CS2001: Source file `(x86)/Mono/lib/gtk-sharp-2.0/atk-sharp.dll' could not be found
error CS2001: Source file `(x86)/Mono/lib/gtk-sharp-2.0/gdk-sharp.dll' could not be found
error CS2001: Source file `(x86)/Mono/lib/gtk-sharp-2.0/gtk-sharp.dll' could not be found
error CS2001: Source file `(x86)/Mono/lib/gtk-sharp-2.0/glib-sharp.dll' could not be found
Compilation failed: 6 error(s), 0 warnings
```

I'm using mono-3.12.0-gtksharp-2.12.26-win32-0.msi, OS: Win7.

All the answer didn't take effect. And I don't have the chance to change the install folder.

It also failed to install XamarinStudio-5.7.0.660-0.msi, the error message:

```
 Gtk# 2.12.22 or greater must be installed
```

Actually the Gtk# 2.12.26 should have been installed.

Comment: It's looking in the wrong directory. I'm currently having the same problem and do not have a solution yet. For some reason it doesn't consider `Program Files (x86)` as one folder, there's probably something escaped the wrong way.